# Ubuntu Server 17 - move EFI to different disk

Tags: boot, raid

I have two hard drives that were configured for software RAID 1. As luck would have it, the one with the boot information is going bad, and needs replaced.  So far, I've managed to break the RAID, but I can't figure out how to boot back into ubuntu using the second disk.

```
lsblk output:

    NAME                     MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                        8:0    0   7.3T  0 disk  
├─sda1                     8:1    0   512M  0 part  
├─sda2                     8:2    0   7.5G  0 part  
├─sda3                     8:3    0  46.6G  0 part  
└─sda4                     8:4    0   7.2T  0 part  
sdc                        8:32   0   7.3T  0 disk  
├─sdc1                     8:33   0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sdc2                     8:34   0   7.5G  0 part  
│ └─md0                    9:0    0   7.5G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sdc3                     8:35   0  46.6G  0 part  
│ └─md1                    9:1    0  46.5G  0 raid1 
│   ├─vg0-lv_os-real     253:0    0  41.9G  0 lvm   
│   │ ├─vg0-lv_os        253:1    0  41.9G  0 lvm   /
│   │ └─vg0-vg0_backup   253:3    0  41.9G  0 lvm   
│   └─vg0-vg0_backup-cow 253:2    0     1G  0 lvm   
│     └─vg0-vg0_backup   253:3    0  41.9G  0 lvm   
└─sdc4                     8:36   0   7.2T  0 part  
  └─md2                    9:2    0   7.2T  0 raid1 /data
sr0                       11:0    1   745M  0 rom
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but as you can see, my root partition is part of a logical volume.

I checked the /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg file, and it looks like:

```
search.fs_uuid 3d9986e9-5f5f-455c-9c0e-b25f6bc78ba3 root lvmid/NQkw8Q-hxYL-TQsW-74go-Zqb6-c8aX-0vznck/rs6Y2v-SyDQ-EGj6-ltOp-otfL-8VH4-dPRz9I
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Where 3d9986e9... is the UUID for the LVM:

```
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv_os: UUID="3d9986e9-5f5f-455c-9c0e-b25f6bc78ba3" TYPE="ext4"
```

Again, all I'm trying to do is remove the bad disk, and boot up using the second disk without losing any existing data.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried lots of different things that came up from various google searches, and finally got my system to boot after removing the faulty drive (/dev/sda).  I'm pretty sure it was a simple matter of running:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdc
```

followed by

```
sudo update-grub
```

Maybe somebody smarter than me can confirm this was all that was needed.  At any rate, my issue has been resolved.  L.D. - thanks for fixing the formatting on my post.